# Any existing Reeds-Shepp implementations?

Tags: graph-algorithms, implementation

Does anyone know of any open source implementations for finding the optimal path of a Reeds-Shepp car?

I'm trying to implement the formulas myself, but I'm having trouble with one of them. I think it's a typo in their paper; their formula just doesn't spit out the expected result.

The specific formula is found in Section 8.3 in Reeds and Shepp's 1990 paper, found [here](http://statistics.wharton.upenn.edu/documents/research/Car%20that%20goes%20forwards%20and%20backwards.pdf). I'm trying to find the optimal path from (x = 0, y = 0, theta = 0) to (x = 0, y = 0, theta = -pi), or put differently: the car goes back to the starting position, but pointed in the opposite direction. The correct solution is shown in Figure D of Section 1. The formula in Section 8.3 should give the same turn lengths, but it doesn't. The three turn lengths should all be pi / 3, but working it out by hand gives me completely different values.

Comment: I think that the question is not research level, however perhaps this can help you: http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/cs326a/rs.c (README: http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/cs326a/README_RS). You can also take a look at Chapter 13 of the book "Planning algorithms": http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch13.pdf

Comment: Thanks! That C code link was exactly what I was looking for. The formula used there is definitely different from the one in the paper, but it gives the correct results.

Comment: As far as the following code goes (http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/cs326a/rs.c) has anyone checked the validity of this code? My initial tests are showing really poor estimates, sometimes overestimating and sometimes underestimating the length. His email does mention it's "for a certain increment of configuration (x,y,phi)" which I'm not certain how to interpret.

Comment: I eventually implemented Reeds-Shepp for my master's thesis using that original link as a guide. Here is [my C# implementation](https://github.com/mattbradley/AutonomousCar/blob/master/AutonomousCar/AutonomousCar/PathFinding/ReedsShepp/ReedsSheppSolver.cs). The solver worked perfectly for all possible Reeds-Shepp paths. Hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy of my comment above (I suppose that the question can be accepted/closed):

I think that the question is not research level, however perhaps this can help you: 
http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/cs326a/rs.c (README: http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/cs326a/README_RS).

You can also take a look at [Chapter 13 of the book "Planning algorithms"](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch13.pdf).

Comment: By the way, how did you find that code?